# How to store object on URL query string

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I am developing a generic search component on React that puts it's filters, current page and some other params on the URL query string (after the `?`).

I currently use the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to transform the query string to js objects and back to query string, as the `react-router-v4` expects

The point is that I need to store an Object within the query string, so I can differentiate the search filter (that can have multiple fields) from other params.

I see that I can [transform a object to JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), and store everything on a filter param, or I could store the object using dot notation (`?filter.name=foo&filter.tag=bar`) or even a square brackets notation (`?filter[name]=foo&filter[tag]=bar`) and treat them accordingly when reading them from the url.

I am tending to choose the JSON notation, but Is there any problems with this approach? Should I know beforehand any limitations? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Hello Murilo, you helped me last week with a question I had for React so I thought I give you my input maybe of some assistance? What I do to pass information to the URL is I use `Link` to pass the variables and then in my Routes, I pass in the param for that specific Route. I can show you an example if you want? I'm not sure if it'll be of any assistance though. I use it all the time to pass information to other Routes which I have access to in the future.

Comment: Good to know that I were helpful :) So, I already use the `Link`, and  sometimes the `push()` method (when a api call return and then I redirect to somewhere), and setting the search param works nicely. The problem here is that on the search string I want to store an entire JS Object

Comment: hmm.. I'm not too sure myself if you can pass json into the URL. I believe you would need to convert that object into a string so that the URL can read it. what I would do is if it was an object, I would parse it using `JSON.stringify` and pass in the string so the url could read it and if you need to use it in your view, I would parse it out again using `JSON.parse` to parse it back into an object.

Comment: yes! that's my first idea. I've seen other 2 options, and I don't know if there are some problems with any of them. I would like to hear from someone that have already done it if there is any problem